# Linux of equivalent CryptProtectMemory

Tags: linux, encryption

I am trying to secure my in-memory data against swap file reads when my process memory will be paged out.

I know CryptProtectMemory() in Windows SDK which can be used to encrypt memory buffers.

I couldn't find any such function on Linux, please let me know if anyone knows.

We can use mlock() so that memory is not paged out, but does that imply my secretes are secure?

Comment: I'm confused :) are you asking for a way to avoid that memory is swapped to file (first sentence) or a way to encrypt in-memory data? mlock() in linux will do the trick for the first part (pages are not swapped to disk)

Comment: I want to encrypt variables, but if that is not possible then I will go with mlock, but before that I want to make sure that using just  mlock is safe.. I understand its not encrypting and I will be relying on kernel memory management to protect my data from other processes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest equivalent in Linux to `CryptProtectMemory()` is [`gcry_malloc_secure()`](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Memory-allocation.html#Memory-allocation) in *libgcrypt*. The secure memory allocated will be locked in memory; `gcry_free()` will zeroize and deallocate it. Other crypto libraries have similar calls, for instance the template [`secure_vector`](http://botan.randombit.net/secmem.html) in Botan.

Another approach is indeed to use the lower-level POSIX call [mlock()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mlock.html) on the whole buffer. The burden of zeroizing the buffer is with you though. You must manually call [memset()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memset.html)) when the buffer is not used anymore or when your program terminates.

`CryptProtectMemory()` seems to do something slightly different than any of the two approaches above: it creates a small, random session key and uses it to encrypt the buffer. The benefit is that you only need to lock and finally zeroize only the very small page where the key resides, and not the whole buffer. That may make a difference if the buffer is very big. However, we will not be able to operate or process data in the buffer. There is also a small time window when secret data is swappable.

Comment: Linking some interesting info about mlock , author : non other than Robert Love [link](https://www.quora.com/Linux/Does-the-Linux-kernel-prevent-mlock-abuse-If-so-how)

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if encrypting (part of the) memory of your process will end up in a chicken-egg problem. I mean, the password to encrypt/decrypt the block(s) of memory of interest should be somewhere in memory, inside the address space of your process. 
If some malicious code can access/inspect your process address space at runtime you are not going to solve the problem (but you are making the observer life harder ;))

If you are working in user space you can build some wrapper to encrypt/decrypt your variables/memory using any available crypto library (ie. OpenSSL libcrypto), I guess. You could create some sort of "secure variable" object, but be aware that some crypto algo requires padding (size of *base types* might need to be modified accordingly)
In kernel space you can use the LKCF (Linux Kernel Crypto API)

Comment: There is such a problem of keeping the secret secret. 

It can be solved though, by using a HW dongle or by using a signed driver with custom memory segmentation, either of which would deliver the password to decrypt the memory only if the process loaded into memory has a hash matching your original process.

Comment: @Motes: It's still a chicken-egg issue. Regardless of how/when the password/key is delivered, it'll be delivered into clear memory of the requested process as it bootstraps the memory encryption procedure. A malicious process can dump the memory at that instant.

Comment: @DeepSpace101 Fair point.  Though risk could be mitigated by using a one time password via a dongle, but also the system could be hardened further by computing the hash all processes loaded on the OS and so the system would only allow the password to be "clear" when the entire OS was in a predetermined state.